# Phrase/Term for someone who thinks they’re still great (even if the aren’t anymore) because of their past achievements?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know there’s a term for that. I just can’t remember.

Comment: Do you mean "has been"?

Comment: Start here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/asking  Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

They are said to be "[resting on their laurels](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rest-on-your-laurels#targetText=rest%20on%20your%20laurels,can%20rest%20on%20your%20laurels.)," so a "[laurels-rester](https://www.google.com/search?ei=BbKCXYvWPMK6sQWjzb1g&q=%22laurels%20rester%22&oq=%22laurels%20rester%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i10i30.8985.11418..11690...0.0..0.89.177.2......0....1..gws-wiz.mDtohzfcV8Q&ved=0ahUKEwjL7K-HuNvkAhVCXawKHaNmDwwQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)" might be a term for someone who does that.

Comment: I like "resting on their laurels."  I'll give you a tip to help you write successful answers here.  You're expected to include a verbatim excerpt from the link.  It's not enough to put in the link -- you're supposed to augment that with an exact quote from the dictionary or other source.

Comment: I'm supposed to?  I did.  The verbatim excerpts from those links *are* included.  They're what's inside the quotations marks.  Those verbatim words come from the links.  If you want to see the source for the verbatim excerpts found in quotes, you need only click on the links.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out.  Creative.